# pandas выбор наиболее частого значения в строке

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'LogReg':pred_2, 'MLCP' : mlcp_pred,'DTC':dtc_pred})
```

у меня есть 3 колонки в датафрейме, как мне выбрать наиболее часто встречающееся значение в строке и записать его в новую колонку:

```
 df['target']
```

значения, которые указаны в переменных строковые

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вариант с методом [`pandas.DataFrame.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html). Метод возвращает фрейм cо значениями в порядке убывания частот. В данном случае забираем первый столбец результата с индексом `[0]` (самое частое значение). При вызове метода указываем аргумент `axis=1` - посчитать [моду](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0_(%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) по каждой строке фрейма.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'LogReg': ['aaa', 'aaa', 'bbb'], 'MLCP': ['ccc', 'bbb', 'ccc'], 'DTC': ['bbb', 'aaa', 'bbb']})
df['target'] = df.mode(axis=1)[0]
print(df)
```

```
  LogReg MLCP  DTC target
0    aaa  ccc  bbb    aaa
1    aaa  bbb  aaa    aaa
2    bbb  ccc  bbb    bbb
```